# Exporting the chart plot by jpg/png using AnyChart, resulting half of the out put

Tags: export, png, jpeg, anychart

Iam using AnyChart * Version: 7.9.0

When i generate the report, it is generating with the proper data and it is plotting in the screen properly (eg. image 1: Chart rendered depends on the output) but when i export the plot by png/jpg it will export half of the out put like in image 2(Exported chart using png/jpg format).

How to achieve to export complete chart.

[Chart rendered depends on the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRRyg.jpg)

[Exported chart using png/jpg format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDMXo.jpg)

json code:

```
{
   "chart":{
      "container":"dashboard:inqByProductsGraphPanalId_1",
      "legend":null,
      "legand":null,
      "tooltip":{
         "padding":null,
         "allowLeaveScreen":false,
         "offsetX":0,
         "offsetY":0,
         "anchor":"center",
         "hideDelay":null,
         "enabled":false,
         "displayMode":null
      },
      "yScale":1,
      "type":"column",
      "title":{
         "enabled":true,
         "text":"Inquiry by Product",
         "width":null,
         "height":null,
         "orientation":"top",
         "align":"center",
         "rotation":null,
         "padding":{
            "top":-10,
            "right":0,
            "bottom":30,
            "left":0
         },
         "useHtml":true,
         "fontSize":11,
         "fontColor":"Black"
      },
      "fill":null,
      "stroke":null,
      "animation":{
         "enabled":false
      },
      "labels":{
         "enabled":true,
         "useHtml":false,
         "position":"centerTop",
         "anchor":"centerBottom",
         "fontColor":"Black",
         "background":null,
         "padding":{
            "top":2,
            "right":2,
            "bottom":2,
            "left":2
         }
      },
      "crosshair":{
         "xLabel":{
            "anchor":"centerTop"
         },
         "yLabel":{
            "anchor":"rightCenter"
         }
      },
      "chartId":"100",
      "series":[
         {
            "data":[
               {
                  "fill":"DarkOliveGreen",
                  "x":"ADIDAS",
                  "value":19,
                  "weekNumber":0,
                  "year":0
               },
               {
                  "fill":"Crimson",
                  "x":"No Product Name Reported",
                  "value":44,
                  "weekNumber":0,
                  "year":0
               },
               {
                  "fill":"Chocolate",
                  "x":"ANACIN",
                  "value":24,
                  "weekNumber":0,
                  "year":0
               },
               {
                  "fill":"DarkMagenta",
                  "x":"AMLODOC",
                  "value":56,
                  "weekNumber":0,
                  "year":0
               }
            ],
            "labels":{
               "enabled":true,
               "useHtml":false,
               "position":"centerTop",
               "anchor":"centerBottom",
               "fontColor":"Black",
               "background":null,
               "padding":{
                  "top":2,
                  "right":2,
                  "bottom":2,
                  "left":2
               }
            },
            "name":null,
            "enabled":true,
            "seriesType":"column",
            "type":null,
            "color":null,
            "xScale":0,
            "yScale":1,
            "selectFill":"Goldenrod",
            "hatchFill":null,
            "hoverHatchFill":"#445444",
            "selectHatchFill":"Plum",
            "select":null,
            "tooltip":null
         }
      ],
      "xScale":0,
      "scales":[
         {
            "type":"ordinal",
            "inverted":false,
            "names":[
               
            ],
            "ticks":null
         },
         {
            "type":"linear",
            "inverted":false,
            "maximum":null,
            "minimum":null,
            "minimumGap":"0.1",
            "maximumGap":"0.1",
            "softMinimum":null,
            "softMaximum":null,
            "stackMode":"none",
            "stickToZero":"true",
            "logBase":"10"
         }
      ],
      "interactivity":{
         "selectionMode":"singleSelect",
         "hoverMode":"byX",
         "spotRadius":null
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You must present code.

Comment: sure..will add asap

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of the library 7.9.0. It's not fully compatible with the current version of the export server that is hosted on export.anychart.com (8.8.0).
To solve the issue you can call saveAsJpg or saveAsPng functions with the manually applied size of the image. Like this:

`chart.saveAsJpg(600, 600);`

Also, you can update your library up to the latest version to avoid incompatibility issues.